# Could Orion capsules be reused?

Tags: design, crewed-spaceflight, orion-spacecraft, economics, capsule

While watching [this video animation](http://vimeo.com/31799422) of Orion EFT-1, a question occurred to me. Previous capsules (Apollo, Gemini, Mercury) were used once and then relegated to museums (apart from a few [test flight articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_2#MOL)). The Space Shuttle was, by design, reusable, even if it never lived up to its initial economic projections.

**Could individual Orion capsules be reconditioned and launched again?**

**EDIT:** The [Space.com](http://www.space.com/21541-nasa-orion-spacecraft-reusable.html) article referenced by TildalWave talks about Orion re-usability in a general way, but I'm hoping someone can dig up somewhat more official references and/or provide greater detail, such as what processes might be required before sending the capsule on its second mission, how many times it could practically be used, etc.

Comment: There's an OK-ish article on this over at [Space.com](http://www.space.com/21541-nasa-orion-spacecraft-reusable.html). If someone was to equip some parts of what's mentioned there with additional info, that would be great. E.g. Spaceflight101 also has an [extensive article on Orion spacecraft](http://www.spaceflight101.com/orion-spacecraft-overview.html). Basically, it's most of the Crew Vehicle that can be refurbished and reused, but not the Service Module, Launch Abort System and heat shield. But, as Spaceflight101 mentions, heat shield might require redesigning for faster reentry anyway.

Comment: @TildalWave This calls for a Wikipedia edit.

Comment: IIRC the capsules were designed to be re-used, but only the things that were cheaply re-used. One lesson of the shuttle was that not everything can be economically re-used.

Comment: Snarky answer:  not if Lockheed has anything to say about it! ;-)

Comment: After checking the date the [Wikipedia article was updated](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Orion_%28spacecraft%29&offset=&limit=500&action=history) to mention reusability, I see that the was on 30 November 2014‎. I assume Bard56 is a person commenting here.

Comment: @mins guilty as charged

Comment: I was answering using Wikipedia information you did add yourself. This reminded me of this [joke](http://www.campingdude.com/content/skit/long_winter-2250.asp), so I removed my answer...

Comment: @JerardPuckett If you're editing that Wiki page then this might be of interest too: http://spacenews.com/lockheed-martin-pressing-to-simplify-orion-heat-shield/ Not anything set in stone yet but something to look for in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they can, at least they are designed to do such. Here's some links supporting that:

- http://www.space.com/21541-nasa-orion-spacecraft-reusable.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_%28spacecraft%29#Crew_module_.28CM.29 " The CM is designed to be refurbished and reused."
- http://www.informationweek.com/government/leadership/nasa-orion-space-capsule-has-surprising-brain/d/d-id/1297427

As for how re-usable it will be, well, only time will tell. There was mention in the above articles of Orion having a kind of plug and play architecture where parts could easily be swapped, meaning that it should be easy to refurbish an Orion, but only time will tell just how easy it is.

From [this article](http://www.bizjournals.com/denver/blog/boosters_bits/2015/02/lockheed-martin-reports-on-orions-first-space.html?ana=yahoo&page=all), comes the phrase:

> Ultimately, LMSS wants each Orion capable of flying on half a dozen missions or more.

I believe LMSS is Lockheed Martin Space Systems, the prime contract on Orion.

Comment: Both the Wiki and the InfoWeek articles link back to the same Space.com article. Is it just this one engineer's opinion that Orion might possibly be reusable, or is this really Lockheed/NASAs plan?

Comment: I'll have to find it, but I know they intend to at least partially re-use the test one done a few months ago. So I'm sure that reuse is intended.

Comment: @JerardPuckett: I found another independent better article, which I added.

Comment: Is it just me, or is "Ultimately ... capable of flying on half a dozen missions or more" not a very ambitious goal in terms of reuse?

Comment: It's consistent with the various designs of COTS. The shuttle was reused, yes, but with some major overhauls between flights. I hope the idea is to have less lifetime, but less work required between flights.