# Is the nosecone of the CST-100 Starliner more than structural?

Tags: cst-100, nosecone

The [CST-100 Starliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CST-100) is Boeing's new crew capsule.  It has a detachable nosecone which serves several structural purposes.  Because the capsule uses a [pusher-style launch escape system](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17783/26446), there is no escape tower, and thus a nosecone is needed for aerodynamics.  The nosecone also covers a docking tunnel during launch and can be jettisoned.

**Does the nosecone perform any other purpose than these structural needs?**  For example, are there any sensors in the nosecone (e.g. a Q-ball)?  Is anything stored in the nosecone?

[image: CST-100 Starliner]